# The getter 'documents' was called on null. Receiver: null Tried calling: documents

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm having a strange problem, I have a bunch of documents inside the **Audiobooks** but when I try to call it using Streambuilder no item appears.

**The error meesssage:**

> The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building
> StreamBuilder(dirty, state: _StreamBuilderBase
> State<QuerySnapshot, AsyncSnapshot>#98258): The getter
> 'documents' was called on null. Receiver: null Tried calling:
> documents

**Note:** when I replace **Audiobooks** with **Training Courses**, the app works and gets the elements inside **Training Courses**. The elements in **Audiobooks** are similar to the elements in **Training Courses**.

```
StreamBuilder(
                        stream: Firestore.instance
                            .collection("Sections")
                            .document("Audiobooks")
                            .collection("All")
                            .orderBy("dateAdded", descending: true)
                            .snapshots(),
                        builder: (context, snapshot) {
                          if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                            return Container(
                              height: 0,
                              width: 0,
                            );
                          }

                          else if(snapshot.hasError)
                          {
                            return Container(
                              height: 0,
                              width: 0,
                            );
                          }

                            else if(snapshot.data == null) return CircularProgressIndicator();

                          else {
                            return GridView.count(
                              shrinkWrap: true,
                              crossAxisCount: 2,
                              primary: true,
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                              physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                              scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,

                              children: List.generate(snapshot.data.documents.length, (index) {
                                DocumentSnapshot item =
                                snapshot.data.documents[index];

                                return Card(
                                  child: Column(
                                    // mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                    children: <Widget>[
                                      Expanded(
                                        child: Stack(
                                          fit: StackFit.expand,
                                          children: <Widget>[
                                            Container(
                                              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                                              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                                image: DecorationImage(
                                                    image: CachedNetworkImageProvider(
                                                      item["img"],
                                                    ),
                                                    fit: BoxFit.cover),
                                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(topRight:  Radius.circular(5), topLeft: Radius.circular(5)),
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                          ],
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                      Padding(
                                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                                        child: Column(
                                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                                          children: <Widget>[
                                            Text(
                                              item["nameAR"],
                                              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                              style: TextStyle(
                                                fontSize: 16.0,
                                                color: GlobalUniversal.blackColor,
                                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                                fontFamily: widget.availableEN == true ? widget.myAppLang != "en" ? FONT_AR : FONT_EN : FONT_AR,),
                                            ),
                                            Text(
                                              widget.availableEN == true ?  widget.myAppLang != "en" ? "${DURATION_AR}: ${item[DURATION_DB]}" : "${DURATION_EN}: ${item[DURATION_DB]}" : "${DURATION_AR}: ${item[DURATION_DB]}",
                                              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey[500]),
                                            ),
                                          ],
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                );
                              }),
                            );
                          }


                        },
                      ),
```

**Audiobooks Path**
[image]

[image]

**Training Courses Path**
[image]

[image]

Comment: The error is telling you that `snapshot.data` is null.  What exactly are you expecting instead?  Please edit the question to state what isn't working the way you expect.  Be sure to call out the line of code where the error happens.

Comment: @Doug Stevenson actually the path is contain a data and it is not null ! the code worked pefectly when get data from "Training Courses" instead of "Audiobooks" then the code have not any problem but I think the problem it's from firestore

Comment: What line of code does the error happen on, and how is behaving different than you expect?